# How to add multiple directories like the name 1-100 in one command

Tags: shell, centos, command-line, command

I need to create multiple directories using one command. 
Is it possible?

Like directory name starts from 1-100.

```
mkdir 1..100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need a (`for`...`do`...`done`) loop; just do

```
mkdir $(seq 1 100)
```

Or, in bash,

```
mkdir {1..100}
```

Comment: It should be mkdir $(seq 1 100),and yes a for loop is not necessary in this case,I just got used to it..

Comment: Or even `mkdir {001..100}`

Answer (score 2):

```
for folder in $(seq 1 100);do mkdir $folder;done
```

Comment: pls high light the cmd

Comment: [root@localhost test1]# $(seq 1 100);do mkdir $folder
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Comment: @Suresh copy the whole command including from the “for”